# Resolve Adv CSS/JS Agg - gzip issue

Tags: css-js-aggregation

I have this issue on my drupal status report. How do I get rid of the warnings on Advagg?

[image]

Comment: Is your site protected with HTTP Auth?

Comment: yes. so how does that relates to this?

Comment: HTTP Auth can cause these checks to fail in the way that you are seeing. Try disabling it and re-checking.